# Move Pivot Item view with focused Internet Explorer control - WP7

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

I put Internet Explorer control on Pivot. I have some information in HTML which I would like to show and I want to have possibility to have Internet Explorer control enabled.

However, every time I click Internet Explorer control I cannot switch my Pivot view as long as IE control has focus. Switching pivot's view is possible when IE control is disabled. How to get similar effect when IE control is enabled? Maybe some trick?

I mean - when I move finger from left-to-right or from right-to-left over IE control - I want to switch Pivot item. When I move finger up-down over IE control - I just want to scroll IE window.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, at least in easy way. Even if you managed to intercept gesture over webbrowser control, you are responsible to handle all of them (can't choose only left-to-right leaving up-down finger movement handled by default webbrowser control gesture-handler).

Comment: You would need to use the PivotHeader to navigate to the different PivotItems. You would also have this problem if you put a map in a pivot

Comment: Using only PivotHeader is not intuitive and this is not comfortable for users. I am interested how can I manage gesture over webbrowser?